# HTTPS://non-www to HTTPS://www IIS rewrite rule

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

Looking for IIS rewrite rule for HTTPS://example.co.uk to HTTPS://www.example.co.uk I have been able to redirect HTTP://example.co.uk & HTTP://www.example.co.uk to HTTPS://www.example.co.uk but unable to create a rule to redirect HTTPS://example.co.uk to HTTPS://www.example.co.uk In IIS the site bindings i have are: http [www.example.co.uk](http://www.example.co.uk) 80 http example.co.uk 80 https [www.example.co.uk](http://www.example.co.uk) 443

```
    <rule name="https" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="https://example.co.uk/*" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:0}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Not very experienced in creating rewrite rules they are already populated from past colleagues
Any assistance would be good : )

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 1):

you could try below rule:

```
 <rule name="RedirectNonWwwToWww" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.co.uk$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for your help Lex & Jalpa. I ended up creating site with https www site and adding redirect to the https domain.com site it works

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: i cant mark my own comment as helpful : ( how can i do that